# In what ways sacrificing several birds interfere with Jewish's ritual?

Tags: halacha

I was looking for sources on why the Jews fought the Romans and what's the real reason. Why the Jews didn't just get along with the rest of the empire.

I found this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gessius_Florus

The sources are mostly Josephus [(The War of the Jews 2:14-5)](https://www.sefaria.org/The_War_of_the_Jews.2.14.4?ven=The_War_of_the_Jews,_translated_by_William_Whiston&vhe=The_Jewish_Wars,_trans._Y.N._Simhoni,_Warsaw,_1923&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), so I probably want to hear more of other sources for balances.

> One notable instance of provocation occurred while the Jews were
> worshiping at their local synagogue and a Hellenist sacrificed several
> birds on top of a chamber pot at the entrance of the synagogue, an act
> that rendered the building ritually unclean. In response to this
> action, the Jews sent a group of men to petition Florus for redress.
> Despite accepting a payment of eight talents to hear the case, Florus
> refused to listen to the complaints and instead had the petitioners
> imprisoned

And that raises a lot of questions:

1. I thought Hashem can only be worshipped at Beith Hamikdash. Yet, a synagogue makes the building ritually unclean?
2. I can't remember anything in the bible about synagogue must be ritually unclean from well, birds. What's going on?
3. The story goes that the Jews paid the governor 8 talents (I presume it means 320 kg of gold) to hear a case. Well, if I spend that kind of money, I want more than just hearing, I wanna win the case. What's goin on here? Why it's that important?

So yea I want to know more about the backstory.

Why would sacrificing some birds outside some synagogue causes problems?

Answer (score 4):

The main reason the Jews fought the Empire was because they preferred liberty. The Great Revolt was only a century after the Romans conquered the Hasmonean Kingdom. The people still had some sense of what it was like to be free and not controlled by a pagan empire.

On your particular questions:

1. Synagogues appeared in the Second Temple Era as places of certain forms of worship: Public readings of the Torah and prayer. But the central place of worship and the only place where sacrifices could be made was still the Temple in Jerusalem. Synagogues have the status of "little sanctuaries" (see for example [Megillah 29a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.29a.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)) and thus are also holy places and so idolatrous practices such as the one that Hellenist did tainted the place.
2. The problem was that the Hellenist was preparing a pagan, idolatrous sacrifice, which taints holy objects and sanctuaries in Judaism. In general, it wouldn't have mattered what he had sacrificed. The problem was the act.
3. Are you asking why Josephus mentioned how much money they paid? Likely to be historically accurate and to show that though they paid a ton of money, nonetheless, Florus, who was a terrible and greedy procurator, didn't care about their petition.

Comment: Yea, you don't spend so much money and get nothing. Whose money is it anyway? So florus response by crucifying some people. The jews have nobody up to complain too? Were jews prosperous and smarter than the rest of romans that they were "resented" again?

Comment: @obfuscated There isn't evidence that the Romans were meaner to Jews more than other people. In fact, the Romans actually went out of their way to let the Jews continue their monotheistic worship in the Temple, even though intolerant monotheism contradicts the pluralistic polytheism of the Romans. But most of the Jews weren't satisfied. They wanted liberty. This led to clashes between the Jews and the Romans. Couple that with tyrannical governors and the end result is pretty obvious.